# Strange border-width behavior in Chrome - Floating point border-width?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Certain fluid designs, especially those involving %-width iFrames, seem to cause some strange rounding-type errors in Chrome (I've got version 21).

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzQJE/14/) demonstrates the problem.  Set the border to an integer pixel value, and the values you get back when you ask for them are floating point numbers slightly smaller than the expected value.

Trying the [exact same code in CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqFgi) doesn't yield the same results, presumably because the iFrame and other styles around it aren't set up the same way.

(I've also seen this behavior for the basic width and height attributes, although I was unable to replicate that part of the problem in jsFiddle.)

This doesn't seem to be a problem in Firefox or in IE8.

Any ideas as to what, specifically, is causing this strange behavior, and how I can work around it to get at the real values?

---

The plot thickens.  In an attempt to shim around the problem, I found that values over 10px do not appear to be subject to the issue.

Also, based on @GionaF's comment, it appears to work properly in Chrome 22.

Comment: Actually, i get 3px (chrome 22)

Comment: Beh.  Thanks for looking at it @GionaF.  Unfortunately, I don't have the option to upgrade at the moment...

Comment: Recently I had an issue with Chrome: trying to position the odd width  block (49px) at the 50% width, I was getting a bit different positions +/- 1 pixel on even and odd screen widths. I solved this adding 1px padding to ensure that the block with is even. Hope this tip help you.

Comment: we have a popular saying, if the murderer waits a bit before murdering his victim, it would die alone :) I have Google Chrome 26.0.1410.64  and that problem does not appear

Comment: Works properly in my version of Chrome(22)

Comment: @ChrisJaynes this works fine for me on Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m.

Comment: @ChrisJaynes, may you add a screenshot to compare?, I'm having the same results with that jsfiddle using lots of configurations (OS, Browser and versions).

Comment: Few months ago i've got a similar issue with Chrome 21: in my case it was a Container of 765px width which i had to define using EM. Ensuing from 16px base font size, the width defined in EM was exactly 47.8125em. Everything worked fine, every browser (including older Chrome versions) rendered exactly 765px except Chrome 21, which rendered 765.066650390625px. The problem of this rounding was that the included subcontainers which were also defined in em units inherited slightly larger widths. At the end the whole fluid layout broke. At the end i had to use px-units.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To reproduce your problem I have to change the zoom-level of Chrome. Changing the zoom-level back to 100% fixes it. It appears to be a bug, the calculated border width is always smaller than the defined border width, zooming in or out!

Your 10px border does give a value of 10 when the zoom-level is 110%, but on 125% it has the same problem as your 3px border.

edit: firefox has the same behavior!

Comment: This is ultimately the most reliable way to recreate the problem. I don't think I had a zoom level set when I initially had the problem, but it's nice to know that it can be recreated by zooming.

Comment: In my case, my zoom was set on 90% (happens occasionally when using the scroll button and Ctrl keys as often as I do), and so my 1px borders were being computed as 1.11px or about 10% wider than they should have been.

Answer (score 15):

I can't reproduce this behavior in Chrome currently, but this behavior most likely has to do with [Subpixel Rendering](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/LayoutUnit).  Essentially, Webkit will do calculations using integer math to avoid floating point imprecision.

It seems that currently, `border` does not use subpixel rendering which may explain why the issue is not visible in new Chrome versions.

Comment: I up-voted this answer, because I think it's probably correct that it has to do with sub-pixel rendering, but I liked that Willem's answer allowed me to at least recreate the behavior. I'm guessing there was a sub-pixel rendering bug in the version of Chrome I was using, perhaps even related to zooming, but it's probably too far back to know for sure. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 4):

Does setting box-sizing to border-box for all elements help at all? This will change the way the box model is calculated where the border and padding won't affect the width.

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check value of `window.devicePixelRatio` in the console. If it is smaller than 1, you will get non-precise values as you describe.

`window.devicePixelRatio` can become smaller than 1 when you're working with an external display and open or close the laptop screen.

Comment: My pixel ratio is 2 and it looks like shit.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the issue with border in `input`s and other elements. After an hour of time spent, I found unexpected reason to cause this problem. Bootstrap css uses `normalize css` and the following code was causing such issue:

```
hr {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

To solve this issue, I override the css in my style.css:

```
hr {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The `hr` rule is really not related with `input`s but it works. This is really unexpected behavior, try it and will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had another example of this with chrome (chromium 76) caused by a `transform: translate()`.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="box-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

`.box-triangle` has an `::after` element shaping a [border triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), which is absolutely positioned on top of `.box-triangle` (right after the padding).
If I set a translate with *%* on `.container` and the resulting percentage isn't an integer then `.box-triangle` border will show slightly under its `::after` element.

Solutions : Using a px translate instead of %, or making sure the percentage of the container dimension is an integer
*Edit* : the exact same thing happen if the transform is applied directly on `.box-triangle` (see last example in snippet)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e55039;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.box-triangle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  color: #f7f1e3;
  background-color: #227093;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

.box-triangle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom-color: #227093;
  border-width: 1.5em;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

[class^='container'] {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 10.5rem;
  width: 20rem;
  /* transform: translate(1%, 1%); */
}

.container-2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 10.5rem;
  width: 20rem;
  transform: translate(0, 5%);
}

.container-3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 20rem;
  transform: translate(0, 5%);
}

.container-4 {
  position: relative;
  height: 168px;
  width: 320px;
  transform: translate(0, 5%);
}

.container-5 {
  position: relative;
  height: 168px;
  width: 320px;
  transform: translate(0, 8px);
}

.noContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 168px;
  width: 320px;
  transform: translate(0, 5%);
}
```

```html
<div class='container-1'>
  <div class="box-triangle">no translate + container height: 10.5 rem (168px)</div>
</div>

<div class='container-2'>
  <div class="box-triangle">translate(0, 5%) + container height: 10.5 rem (168px)</div>
</div>

<div class='container-3'>
  <div class="box-triangle">translate(0, 5%) + container height: 10rem (160px)</div>
</div>

<div class='container-4'>
  <div class="box-triangle">translate(0, 5%) + container height: 168px</div>
</div>

<div class='container-5'>
  <div class="box-triangle">translate(0, 8px) + container height: 168px</div>
</div>

<div class="box-triangle noContainer">No container + translate(0, 5%) + height: 168px</div>
```