# CSS - border-width in em's

Tags: html, css

I have div with id="example" and I set font-size: 14px, border-width: 0.5em; 
The question is, why in browser border-width is 6.4px and not 7px?

```js
var elt = document.getElementById('example');
var width = window.getComputedStyle(elt).borderTopWidth;
elt.textContent = width;
```

```css
#example {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-top: 0.5em solid #ff00ff;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: What browser do you use ?

Comment: Chrome https://s12.postimg.org/s3bebf8pp/dwqdwqtu_u.png

Comment: What version of it ? I've got Chrome 55 and there's no problem.

Comment: i get 6.25px in my mozilla browser.

Comment: Chrome v.54.0.2840.99

Comment: Have you changed your zoom-level ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863430/strange-border-width-behavior-in-chrome-floating-point-border-width

Comment: No, I didn't change it

Comment: How does the snippet work for you now that it displays the computed border width?

Comment: Type CTRL-0 to ensure that your screen is at the default zoom level. I managed to get 6.4 when I zoomed in a couple of steps, 6.25 when I zoomed out a couple of steps, etc.

Comment: It's still the same https://s13.postimg.org/evkly6z3b/sdsadsa.png

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863430/strange-border-width-behavior-in-chrome-floating-point-border-width